# Shaun the Sheep games rules?

Tags: shaun-the-sheep

Recently I bought some Shaun the Sheep games from kosmos.de, but the rules are in German. Does anyone know the rules for next two games :

- [card game](https://www.kosmos.de/content/fileadmin/Media/Anleitungen_FAQ/shaun_das_schaf_komme_was_wolle.pdf)
- [board game](http://www.kosmos.de/kosmos/wrs/wrs.nsf/$WebFirstSourceDiashow/FSE03CB301C1CCE45BC1257532001E49FC?openDocument&_lang=EN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A German friend of mine translated the card game (I also bought it in Germany, but can't read German), it is available here: [Translation of Shaun the sheep card game](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E5Q4pf_CTP3kNiyWrx9gQSWer4NlRT6gvnNj5mKm1mc/edit?hl=en)

Comment: it would be better to copy text in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I used to work for [Aardman](http://www.aardman.com/), the creators of [Shaun the Sheep](http://www.aardman.com/tv-shorts/our-properties/shaun-the-sheep-series-1-and-2/). The following comes straight from the lovely ladies in their [Rights & Licensing department](http://www.aardman.com/rights/).

> "The games are a German design and
>   license, they don't exist in English
>   speaking markets, so only German
>   language instructions I'm afraid."

It might be worth trying [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/)?

Comment: It sounds like time for someone to point out that ALL OF EUROPE is essentially part of the English speaking market place... if available in the EU, it's also available to native english speakers by postal order and English access to the EU by rail and ferry. They need to be disabused of their provincialism.

Comment: @aramis - Lol - Disabused of their provincialism, via the medium of an infant plasticene sheep?